# React using context, and useRef not acting as expected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-context, use-ref

So, I'm using useContext along with useRef to store user information for a simple blog app. Let me show you the code, and after the first snippet I'll explain the issue:

**Login.jsx**

```
import "./login.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { Context } from "../../../context/Context";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Login() {
  const userRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const { user, dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/auth/login", {
        username: userRef.current,
        password: passwordRef.current,
      });
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE" });
    }
  };
///////////////////console.log('user: '+ user)
  return (
    <div className="login">
      <span className="login--title">Login</span>
      <form className="login--form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="login--input"
          placeholder="Enter your username..."
          ref={userRef}
        />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="login--input"
          placeholder="Enter your password..."
          ref={passwordRef}
        />
        <button className="login--btn" type="submit">
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
      <button className="login--register-btn">
        <Link className="link" to="/register">
          Register
        </Link>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Now using the console.log for user I get user: null , instead of the expected user object?** Below is the rest of my current context setup.

**Context.js**

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import Reducer from "./Reducer";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};

export const Context = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, INITIAL_STATE);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Reducer.Js**

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_START":
      return {
        user: null,
        isFetching: true,
        error: false,
      };
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        user: action.payload,
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case "LOGIN_FAILURE":
      return {
        user: null,
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
      };
    case "UPDATE_START":
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      };
    case "UPDATE_SUCCESS":
      return {
        user: action.payload,
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
      };
    case "UPDATE_FAILURE":
      return {
        user: state.user,
        isFetching: false,
        error: true,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        user: null,
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Reducer;
```

I also have a basic Actions setup, but I'm just doing

```
dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data })
```

instead of

```
dispatch(LoginSuccess(res.data))
```

Please note that I'm learning as I go, and I **GREATLY** appreciate the help.

Comment: The actual value of an input is not available in ref.current, it is available in ref.current.value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the handleSubmit function try catch block, username and password if pointing to ref.current,for value it should point to ref.current.value

```
try {
      const res = await axios.post("/auth/login", {
        username: userRef.current.value,
        password: passwordRef.current.value, 
      });
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE" });
    }
```

Comment: Sorry sorry, that's how I originally had it ref.current.value but I was messing around and forgot to put it back. I'm about to tackle the problem again--- will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Yeah, I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: I got it to work :) not sure why it wasn't working originally. The server is just responding a little slow. Thanks for the help.